# how to set default numeric all value in ssrs report parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I want to display all values of a numeric column as a default value in a numeric parameter. With non-numeric/text column, I have used select 'All' and it is selecting all values of that column. But select 'all' or select '%' or select '%[0-9]%' is giving me error in numeric column. I don't want to use "allow multiple values' option Can anyone help me.

I expect parameter to populate all numeric values by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way to do this for numeric parameters without multi values is to do a union all your parameter value with a -1 and call it select all.

So if your parameter (@numcolumn) values were like this

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

then you simply append a -1 using the union all

like this. (varchar(5) is just a choice to show example.. choose something that suits your needs)

```
   select -1 as value
,'Select All' as value_name
    union all
     select mycolumn as value
,cast(mycolumn as varchar(5)) as value_name
 from mytable
```

so now your @numcolumn parameter list will be like this

```
value   value_name
 -1     select All

 1       1

 2       2

 3       3
```

Then in your where clause for your dataset, you set your parameter value like this.

```
where ( @numcolumn = -1 or sometable.somecolumn = @numcolumn)
```

so if you select -1 as your parameter value, then the query will return everything.. else it will filter by the selected value from the parameter.

To make the parameter selection look tidy.. set the @numcolumn parameter value to value and parameter label to value_name

Hope that made sense!

Comment: It worked!! Thanks. In SSRS parameter dropdown, I'm getting default value as  -1. Can it be displayed as 'All' instead of -1

Comment: I think you meant cast(mycolumn as varchar(5)) as value_name instead of case(mycolumn as varchar(5)) as value_name. It worked. Many Thanks,Harry!

Comment: @Jals thanks for pointing it out.. have edited it to case cast instead of case.. typo! DOH